# How do I add text in front of $_Post?

Tags: php, sql, sendmail

I am a complete PHP newbie and I have a specific question that might seem dumb.  However, I cannot seem to locate an answer (likely because I don't know the best search terms).  I am building a sendmail script and I want to add text in front of the items I have pulled from the DB. 
IE:
First Name:
Middle Name:
Last Name:

```
$message = $_POST['fname']."\n".$_POST['mname']."\n".$_POST['lname']."\n".$_POST['role']."\n".$_POST['facility']."\n".$_POST['specialty']."\n".$_POST['level']."\n".$_POST['email'];
```

Comment: I now have this...

        $message = $_POST['fname']."\nMiddle Name:  ".$_POST['mname']."\nLast Name:   ".$_POST['lname']."\nRole:   ".$_POST['role']."\nFacility:   ".$_POST['facility']."\nSpecialty:   ".$_POST['specialty']."\nLevel:   ".$_POST['level']."\nE-Mail:   ".$_POST['email'];

I am still not able to get the code correct for the First Name (prior to the first $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, go and read some basic PHP book. Don't consider that watching video lesson or reading few articles will be enough.

Second of all, understand what you are trying to do. $_POST is a global array, containing all data, sent to server by client via POST method.

I don't completely understand, what you are trying to achieve, but try this one:

```
$message = 'First name: ' . $_POST['fname'] . "\n Middle name: ".$_POST['mname']. 'etc....';
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I needed.  I have purchased two books, but I have to learn on the go.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1913413 No problem! Good luck in your learning ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're already inserting newlines, just add text in the same way...

Comment: How about in front of the first $_POST?  ['fname']
I keep breaking breaking the code.

Comment: `$message = "Text before fname" . $_POST['fname']`